# Evaluate but first complete the square?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Not even sure how to start on this one, walking me through completing the square would be helpful. I'm sure after that I can just apply a trig sub and finish the problem. It'd be extra cool if you walked me through the problem, though.

The problem:

> Evaluate
>
> $$ \int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}} \text{d}x $$
>
> by first completing the square.

Comment: There's a quadratic term of $4x-x^2$ in the bottom. What do you get when you complete the square on it?

Comment: Do you not recall how to complete the square?

Comment: @ahmed the negative in front of the x^2 was throwing me off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}} dx$$
$$=\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}} dx$$
We now apply the substitution $x-2=u$
$$=\int\frac{(u+2)^2}{\sqrt{4-u^2}} du$$
The denominator is now ready for a simple trig substitution $u= 2\sin(t)$

Comment: Nice solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

If $-(a+x)^2=C+4x-x^2$ what would the value of $a$ need to be ?
\begin{eqnarray*}
4x-x^2=4-(4-4x+x^2)=4-(2-x)^2=2^2-(2-x)^2
\end{eqnarray*}
How does help with you're integral ? 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{x^2  \ dx}{ \sqrt{4x-x^2}}=\int \frac{x^2  \ dx}{\sqrt{ 2^2-(2-x)^2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
We would like the content of the square root to look like $1-\cos^2 \theta$. How will we do this ?

Let $2-x=2 \cos \theta \ $  so $ dx= \sin \theta  \ d\theta \ $ & our integral becomes 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{x^2  \ dx}{ \sqrt{4x-x^2}}=\frac{4}{2} \int (1- \cos \theta)^2 \ d\theta
\end{eqnarray*}
Now expand the bracket &  recall that the double angle formula for $\cos \theta$ gives $\cos^2 \theta=\frac{1+ \cos 2\theta}{2}$ now integrate term by term 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \int (1- 2\cos \theta  +\cos^2\theta ) d\theta =2 \left(\theta - 2\sin  \theta + \frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{4} \sin 2\theta \right)+c
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute back in to replace $\theta$ by $x$ and we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{x^2  \ dx}{ \sqrt{4x-x^2}}=3 \cos^{-1}(  \frac{2-x}{2}) -2\sqrt{4x-x^2} + \frac{(2-x)}{4} \sqrt{4x-x^2} +c
\end{eqnarray*}